# Convert string data into data frame

Tags: r, regex, string

I am new to R, any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is the data:

```
coordinates <- "(-79.43591570873059, 43.68015339477487), (-79.43491506339724, 43.68036886994886), (-79.43394727223847, 43.680578504490335), (-79.43388162422195, 43.68058996121469), (-79.43281544978878, 43.680808044458765), (-79.4326971769691, 43.68079658822322)"
```

I would like this to become:

```
Latitude           Longitude
-79.43591570873059 43.68015339477487
-79.43491506339724 43.68036886994886
-79.43394727223847 43.680578504490335
-79.43388162422195 43.68058996121469
-79.43281544978878 43.680808044458765
-79.4326971769691  43.68079658822322
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(Latitude = str_extract_all(coordinates, "(?<=\\()-\\d+\\.\\d+")[[1]], 
      Longitude = str_extract_all(coordinates, "(?<=,\\s)\\d+\\.\\d+(?=\\))")[[1]])
df
#            Latitude          Longitude
#1 -79.43591570873059  43.68015339477487
#2 -79.43491506339724  43.68036886994886
#3 -79.43394727223847 43.680578504490335
#4 -79.43388162422195  43.68058996121469
#5 -79.43281544978878 43.680808044458765
#6  -79.4326971769691  43.68079658822322
```

`Latitude` captures the negative decimal number from opening round brackets (`(`) whereas `Longitude` captures it from comma (`,`) to closing round brackets (`)`).

Or without regex lookahead and behind and capturing it together using `str_match_all`

```
df <- data.frame(str_match_all(coordinates, 
                        "\\((-\\d+\\.\\d+),\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)")[[1]][, c(2, 3)])
```

To convert data into their respective types, you could use `type.convert`

```
df <- type.convert(df)
```

Comment: This creates `Latitude` and `Longitude` as factor variables which could cause difficulties.

Comment: @dcarlson Updated the answer for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `scan` with a little `gsub`:

```
matrix(scan(text = gsub("[()]", "", coordinates), sep = ","), 
       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Lat", "Long")))
# Read 12 items
#            Lat     Long
# [1,] -79.43592 43.68015
# [2,] -79.43492 43.68037
# [3,] -79.43395 43.68058
# [4,] -79.43388 43.68059
# [5,] -79.43282 43.68081
# [6,] -79.43270 43.68080
```

The precision is still there--just truncated in the matrix display.

Two clear advantages:

- Fast.
- Handles multi-element "coordinates" vector (eg: `coordinates <- rep(coordinates, 10)` as an input).

---

Here's another option:

```
library(data.table)
fread(gsub("[()]", "", gsub("), (", "\n", toString(coordinates), fixed = TRUE)), header = FALSE)
```

The `toString(coordinates)` is for cases when `length(coordinates) > 1`. You could also use `fread(text = gsub(...), ...)` and skip using `toString`. I'm not sure of the advantages or limitations of either approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option:

```
coordinates <- "(-79.43591570873059, 43.68015339477487), (-79.43491506339724, 43.68036886994886), (-79.43394727223847, 43.680578504490335), (-79.43388162422195, 43.68058996121469), (-79.43281544978878, 43.680808044458765), (-79.4326971769691, 43.68079658822322)"
coordinates <- gsub("^\\(|\\)$", "", coordinates)
x <- strsplit(coordinates, "\\), \\(")[[1]]
df <- data.frame(lat=sub(",.*$", "", x), lng=sub("^.*, ", "", x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df
```

The strategy here is to first strip the leading trailing parentheses, then string split on `\), \(` to generate a single character vector with each latitude/longitude pair.  Finally, we generate a data frame output.

```
                 lat                lng
1 -79.43591570873059  43.68015339477487
2 -79.43491506339724  43.68036886994886
3 -79.43394727223847 43.680578504490335
4 -79.43388162422195  43.68058996121469
5 -79.43281544978878 43.680808044458765
6  -79.4326971769691 43.68079658822322
```

Comment: This creates `lat` and `lng` as factor variables which could cause difficulties.

Comment: @dcarlson Then use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another base R version with a bit of regex, relying on the fact that replacing the punctuation with blank lines will mean they get skipped on import.

```
read.csv(text=gsub(")|(, |^)\\(", "\n", coordinates), col.names=c("lat","long"), header=FALSE)
#        lat     long
#1 -79.43592 43.68015
#2 -79.43492 43.68037
#3 -79.43395 43.68058
#4 -79.43388 43.68059
#5 -79.43282 43.68081
#6 -79.43270 43.68080
```

Advantages:

- Deals with vector input as well like the other `scan` answer.
- Converts to correct numeric types in output

Disadvantages:

- Not super fast

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rm_round` from `qdapRegex`

```
library(qdapRegex)
read.csv(text = rm_round(coordinates, extract = TRUE)[[1]], header = FALSE,
      col.names = c('lat', 'lng'))
#    lat      lng
#1 -79.43592 43.68015
#2 -79.43492 43.68037
#3 -79.43395 43.68058
#4 -79.43388 43.68059
#5 -79.43282 43.68081
#6 -79.43270 43.68080
```

---

Or in combination with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
rm_round(coordinates, extract = TRUE)[[1]] %>%
     tibble(col1 = .) %>%
     separate(col1, into = c('lat', 'lng'), sep= ",\\s*", convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#    lat   lng
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 -79.4  43.7
#2 -79.4  43.7
#3 -79.4  43.7
#4 -79.4  43.7
#5 -79.4  43.7
#6 -79.4  43.7
```